# DeprecationWarning, MongoNetworkError

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, promise

Here is my database connection code

```
'use strict';

const config = require('../config');
const Mongoose = require('mongoose').connect(config.dbURI);

const mongoose = require('mongoose');

var options = {
    promiseLibrary: require('bluebird'), useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true
};

var mongodbUri = 'mongodb+srv://chatcat:chatcat@mychatcatdb-xlous.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority'
mongoose.connect(mongodbUri, options);
var conn = mongoose.connection;

conn.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));

module.exports = {
    Mongoose
}
```

I'm getting this type of warning. i have also installed all of the packages which is required.
warning is just be like (node:17592) DeprecationWarning, (node:17592) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning.
what is the reason behind the this type of Warning ?
i just started learning node js.
please anyone help me to solve this warning?

```
D:\Node\ChatCAT\ChatCAT_Begin>node server
(node:17592) DeprecationWarning: current URL string parser is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new parser, pass option { useNewUrlParser: true } to MongoClient.connect.
chatCat Running on Port:  3000
(node:17592) DeprecationWarning: current Server Discovery and Monitoring engine is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new Server Discover and Monitoring engine, pass option { useUnifiedTopology: true } to the MongoClient constructor.
connection error: MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [mychatcatdb-shard-00-02-xlous.mongodb.net:27017] on first connect [MongoNetworkError: connection 5 to mychatcatdb-shard-00-02-xlous.mongodb.net:27017 closed
    at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (D:\Node\ChatCGV9Jm2u7rmsCe65wKzPTw5jtS38n2tVEGiDtbLrcW77HPEwrJM2Ej2yFNYwonnection.js:372:9)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:418:26)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:311:20)
    at net.js:668:12
    at TCP.done (_tls_wrap.js:556:7) {
  name: 'MongoNetworkError',
  [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {}
}]
    at Pool.<anonymous> (D:\Node\ChatCGV9Jm2u7rmsCe65wKzPTw5jtS38n2tVEGiDtbLrcW77HPEwrJM2Ej2yFNYwerver.js:438:11)
    at Pool.emit (events.js:311:20)
    at D:\Node\ChatCGV9Jm2u7rmsCe65wKzPTw5jtS38n2tVEGiDtbLrcW77HPEwrJM2Ej2yFNYwool.js:561:14
    at D:\Node\ChatCGV9Jm2u7rmsCe65wKzPTw5jtS38n2tVEGiDtbLrcW77HPEwrJM2Ej2yFNYwool.js:1008:9
    at callback (D:\Node\ChatCGV9Jm2u7rmsCe65wKzPTw5jtS38n2tVEGiDtbLrcW77HPEwrJM2Ej2yFNYwonnect.js:97:5)
    at D:\Node\ChatCGV9Jm2u7rmsCe65wKzPTw5jtS38n2tVEGiDtbLrcW77HPEwrJM2Ej2yFNYwonnect.js:124:7
    at _callback (D:\Node\ChatCGV9Jm2u7rmsCe65wKzPTw5jtS38n2tVEGiDtbLrcW77HPEwrJM2Ej2yFNYwonnect.js:349:5)
    at Connection.errorHandler (D:\Node\ChatCGV9Jm2u7rmsCe65wKzPTw5jtS38n2tVEGiDtbLrcW77HPEwrJM2Ej2yFNYwonnect.js:365:5)    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:418:26)
    at Connection.emit (events.js:311:20)
    at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (D:\Node\ChatCGV9Jm2u7rmsCe65wKzPTw5jtS38n2tVEGiDtbLrcW77HPEwrJM2Ej2yFNYwonnection.js:370:12)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:418:26)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:311:20)
    at net.js:668:12
    at TCP.done (_tls_wrap.js:556:7) {
  name: 'MongoNetworkError',
  [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {}
}
(node:17592) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [mychatcatdb-shard-00-02-xlous.mongodb.net:27017] on first connect [MongoNetworkError: connection 5 to mychatcatdb-shard-00-02-xlous.mongodb.net:27017 closed
    at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (D:\Node\ChatCGV9Jm2u7rmsCe65wKzPTw5jtS38n2tVEGiDtbLrcW77HPEwrJM2Ej2yFNYwonnection.js:372:9)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:418:26)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:311:20)
    at net.js:668:12
    at TCP.done (_tls_wrap.js:556:7) {
  name: 'MongoNetworkError',
  [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {}
}]
    at Pool.<anonymous> (D:\Node\ChatCGV9Jm2u7rmsCe65wKzPTw5jtS38n2tVEGiDtbLrcW77HPEwrJM2Ej2yFNYwerver.js:438:11)
    at Pool.emit (events.js:311:20)
    at D:\Node\ChatCGV9Jm2u7rmsCe65wKzPTw5jtS38n2tVEGiDtbLrcW77HPEwrJM2Ej2yFNYwool.js:561:14
    at D:\Node\ChatCGV9Jm2u7rmsCe65wKzPTw5jtS38n2tVEGiDtbLrcW77HPEwrJM2Ej2yFNYwool.js:1008:9
    at callback (D:\Node\ChatCGV9Jm2u7rmsCe65wKzPTw5jtS38n2tVEGiDtbLrcW77HPEwrJM2Ej2yFNYwonnect.js:97:5)
    at D:\Node\ChatCGV9Jm2u7rmsCe65wKzPTw5jtS38n2tVEGiDtbLrcW77HPEwrJM2Ej2yFNYwonnect.js:124:7
    at _callback (D:\Node\ChatCGV9Jm2u7rmsCe65wKzPTw5jtS38n2tVEGiDtbLrcW77HPEwrJM2Ej2yFNYwonnect.js:349:5)
    at Connection.errorHandler (D:\Node\ChatCGV9Jm2u7rmsCe65wKzPTw5jtS38n2tVEGiDtbLrcW77HPEwrJM2Ej2yFNYwonnect.js:365:5)    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:418:26)
    at Connection.emit (events.js:311:20)
    at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (D:\Node\ChatCGV9Jm2u7rmsCe65wKzPTw5jtS38n2tVEGiDtbLrcW77HPEwrJM2Ej2yFNYwonnection.js:370:12)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:418:26)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:311:20)
    at net.js:668:12
    at TCP.done (_tls_wrap.js:556:7)
(node:17592) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:17592) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
connection error: MongooseError [MongooseServerSelectionError]: connection <monitor> to 3.7.80.251:27017 closed
    at new MongooseServerSelectionError (D:\Node\ChatCGV9Jm2u7rmsCe65wKzPTw5jtS38n2tVEGiDtbLrcW77HPEwrJM2Ej2yFNYwction.js:22:11)
    at NativeConnection.Connection.openUri (D:\Node\ChatCGV9Jm2u7rmsCe65wKzPTw5jtS38n2tVEGioose\lib\connection.js:823:32)
    at Mongoose.connect (D:\Node\ChatCGV9Jm2u7rmsCe65wKzPTw5jtS38n2tVEGioose\lib\index.js:333:15)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Node\ChatCAT\ChatCAT_Begin\app\db\index.js:33:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1178:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1002:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:901:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1044:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:77:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Node\ChatCGV9Jm2u7rmsCe65wKzPTw5jtS38n2tVEGi.js:5:12)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1178:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1002:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:901:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1044:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:77:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Node\ChatCAT\ChatCAT_Begin\app\index.js:11:11)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1178:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1002:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:901:14) {
  message: 'connection <monitor> to 3.7.80.251:27017 closed',
  name: 'MongooseServerSelectionError',
  reason: TopologyDescription {
    type: 'ReplicaSetNoPrimary',
    setName: null,
    maxSetVersion: null,
    maxElectionId: null,
    servers: Map {
      'mychatcatdb-shard-00-00-xlous.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription],
      'mychatcatdb-shard-00-01-xlous.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription],
      'mychatcatdb-shard-00-02-xlous.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription]
    },
    stale: false,
    compatible: true,
    compatibilityError: null,
    logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null,
    heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
    localThresholdMS: 15,
    commonWireVersion: null
  },
  [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {}
}
(node:17592) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongooseServerSelectionError: connection <monitor> to 3.7.80.251:27017 closed
    at new MongooseServerSelectionError (D:\Node\ChatCGV9Jm2u7rmsCe65wKzPTw5jtS38n2tVEGiDtbLrcW77HPEwrJM2Ej2yFNYwction.js:22:11)
    at NativeConnection.Connection.openUri (D:\Node\ChatCGV9Jm2u7rmsCe65wKzPTw5jtS38n2tVEGioose\lib\connection.js:823:32)
    at Mongoose.connect (D:\Node\ChatCGV9Jm2u7rmsCe65wKzPTw5jtS38n2tVEGioose\lib\index.js:333:15)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Node\ChatCAT\ChatCAT_Begin\app\db\index.js:33:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1178:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1002:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:901:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1044:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:77:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Node\ChatCGV9Jm2u7rmsCe65wKzPTw5jtS38n2tVEGi.js:5:12)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1178:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1002:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:901:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1044:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:77:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Node\ChatCAT\ChatCAT_Begin\app\index.js:11:11)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1178:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1002:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:901:14)
(node:17592) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 2)
```

Comment: Hello, I think the unhandled promise is because you could not connect to the DB. Your connection might be timing out. DId you inspect the network request?

Comment: first of all, hide your server and other details

Comment: after it, are you able to connect to your remote server from the server itself ie locally?

Comment: Make sure that your SSL/TLS settings match the server.  If you connect without TLS to a server using requireTLS, the connection gets summarily closed.